# HTML5 Play Audio Every _ Amount of Sec

Tags: jquery, playback, html5-audio, intervals

What I'm trying to do is have it so that when the page loads have it play highpitchsound.wav (or .mp3) for x amount of seconds the user defines in an alertbox on page load.

In the alertbox there's a textbox, and a button "Confirm". The default text is 5 for 5s, or 5000 for 5000ms.

I've used intervals with jquery before, messed with audio in html5 a couple times here, and there, not sure how to combine the two for this, and also don't know how I'd make a custom alertbox onload.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Audio Play Interval</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio autoplay="true">
        <source src="sounds/highpitchsound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        <source src="sounds/highpitchsound.wav" type="audio/wav" />
        <source src="sounds/highpitchsound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a side note, it may be better to ask for seconds from the user rather than milliseconds, and then do the conversion yourself - the general populace doesn't do milliseconds well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Understanding

You can achieve this by referencing the audio element specifically as an object. Because jquery does not extend `HTMLAudioElement` yet you have to specifically refer to the first record within the jquery object for the audio element.

You can then simply reference any of the functions such as `.play()`, `.pause()` or `.load()` from then on.

You can do this simply like so:

```
setInterval(function() { $('audio')[0].play(); },1000);
```

**Breaking this down**

- We use `setInterval(a(),b)` to run the function `a()` every `b` amount of milliseconds
- reference the audio html object in the dom `$('audio')` and then select the `HTMLAudioElement` object within that to interact with it (`$('audio')[0]`)
- then we can simply use any of the functions within that ( i.e `.play()` )

---

### Solution

Now, in order to achieve what you want you can do this,

**Javascript:**

```
startplaying(parseInt(prompt('in milliseconds, set an interval!')));

function startplaying(time) {
    var run = setInterval(function() { $('audio')[0].play(); }, time);
}
```

this first prompts the user to write in a time and then executes the function with the time set out by the user with a touch of validation.

- **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJ3R4/)**